# jQuery Mobile going previous page

Tags: jquery, mobile, navbar

I have a web developed with jQuery Mobile, I'm using navbar in one of the HTML, I have 4 data-role="pages", that would be each one of the nav bars. I have a "back" button, but I need it to take me back to the previous page, not to the previous tab that I'd been to.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the window.history.back() function when the button is clicked.  As an example:

HTML:

```
<a id="back-button">Back</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#back-button").click(function() {
    window.history.back()
});
```

See the [Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history).